# Can I use COUNTIF function with or in GETPIVOTDATA?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a pivot table something like this...

```
Duration  
Run#| Product A | Product B  | Product C |  
01  |  2:01:00  |            |  2:45:00  |
02  |  2:02:00  |            |  2:45:00  |
03  |           |  2:04:00   |  2:45:00  |  
04  |  2:03:00  |  2:02:00   |  2:45:00  |  
...
SUM |  6:06:00  |  4:06:00   | 11:00:00  |
```

I would like to use use GETPIVOTDATA to find an average of the times in the pivot table (not the source data)

So, my averages would be...

```
Product A | Product B  | Product C |  
2:02:00   |  2:03:00   |  2:45:00  |
```

**Can accomplish that with GETPIVOTDATA? If so, how?**

If not, is there another function available?

I have already built the average in a 2nd table using the Sum and a "count" function but it uses table references (i.e., COUNT(B4:B49)) which are a bit clunky since my pivot table will grow over time as more "runs" are completed (past row 49 which is the row of the latest run).

Comment: I don't think it can be done with `GETPIVOTDATA` but you could use a variable row counter and wrap it in a indirect formula. Here is an example for Product A `=AVERAGE(INDIRECT("B4:B"&COUNTA(A4:A10000)))`

Comment: Something like this will grow with the Table; `=AVERAGE(B4:INDEX(B:B,MATCH(1E+99,B:B)-1))`.  It basically finds the range starting in B4 to the last row with number minus one so it does not include the total.

Comment: Thanks to both of you.  I have very good intentions to learn how to use Index and MATCH better but it's nice to get your help.  I used Scott C's formula as the final so if you want to post as an answer, I'll mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will grow with the Table:

```
=AVERAGE(B4:INDEX(B:B,MATCH(1E+99,B:B)-1))
```

It basically finds the range starting in B4 to the last row with number minus one so it does not include the total.